# HSL to HEX mistakes with Sass' adjust-color

Tags: css, colors, sass

I've been trying to figure this out for a month now, but nothing is working. I have 3 colors I need to calculate the differences between in HSL. And I did and applied the differences using adjust-color so that I can later add another color as the base.

But HSL to HEX is not converting properly everywhere. In primary-dark case, it returns the color that I want (which is #154360). But in primary-light case it doesn't (the color I'm trying to get is #5499C7, the one that I actually get is #5298c7). And it makes no sense because I calculated everything correctly, there shouldn't be a problem.

Here's what I wrote:

```
$primary: hsl(204, 64%, 44%);
$primary-dark: adjust-color($primary, $lightness: -21%, $hue: -1deg);
$primary-light: adjust-color($primary, $saturation: -13%, $lightness: 11%);
```

And here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NgQdQL)!

What is going on here? I've been reading everything I could find and going through SO like crazy, asking questions about it, but nothing!
Help, anyone!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simply a matter of rounding numbers in a different way than you expected.

Of course RGB and HEX are basically the same three pairs of numbers and conversion between them is seamless, however HSL conversion is more complicated than that. I'm not going into the math, but [here it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSL) if anybody wanted to read.

Notice that in the element inspector console (in Chrome) you can click the colored square next to color value and change between HSL, RGBA and HEX. If you change your "correct" HEX to HSL and back to HEX, you will get your "incorrect" HEX. It's probably how rounding this calculation itself works and not a problem with SASS itself.

To fix the problem I'd probably suggest using native HSL values instead of casting them to HEX, unless that's necessary in your code. [Support for HSL](http://caniuse.com/#search=hsl) seems pretty good.